# Is modular Barrett reduction usable for Ed25519?

Tags: algorithm-design, reference-request, sha-2, ed25519

I currently try to implement Ed25519 following this [draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-josefsson-eddsa-ed25519-02). I have implemented every field operation except the reduction by the group order $q$ (in chapter 5). I looked for a reduction algorithm and found montgomery reduction and barrett reduction. Because Barrett reduction seems to be more fitting I tried to understand how to implement it (mainly using [this](http://www.nayuki.io/page/barrett-reduction-algorithm)).

What I don't understand is how I can reduce a SHA512 hash by $q$, as the maximum possible value to reduce is ca. $2^{504}$ ($q$ is $2^{252}$, meaning $q^{2} = 2^{504}$). Is there a trick to reduce it in a step before that (like in curve25519 with $2^{256-38}$) or is Barrett reduction simply not usable here? (I don't necessarily need the fastest method available, a simple working one would be enough.)

Comment: The order is still pretty close to a power-of-two, so you can use a variant of the approach described at: [What are the computational benefits of primes close to the power of 2?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24014/what-are-the-computational-benefits-of-primes-close-to-the-power-of-2)

Comment: A simple (but inefficient) method to reduce X, goes somehow as follows: You initialize $t=q<<256$. Then, you make a loop with 257 repetitions and in each step you subtract $t$ from $X$ if you have $X>t$, and you set $t=t>>1$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $q = 2^{252} + n$ for $n < 2^{125}$.  Consequently, $2^{252} \equiv -n \pmod q$, so $$2^{504} \equiv (2^{252})^2 \equiv (-n)^2 \equiv n^2 \pmod q.$$  Since $n^2 < 2^{250}$, you can reduce $$2^{504} x_{\mathrm{hi}} + x_{\mathrm{lo}} \equiv n^2 x_{\mathrm{hi}} + x_{\mathrm{lo}} \pmod q.$$  Since the original input was only 512 bits long, $x_{\mathrm{hi}} < 2^8$, so we can set the bound $$n^2 x_{\mathrm{hi}} < 2^{250} 2^8 = 2^{253} < 2^{253} n + n^2 = q^2 - 2^{504},$$ which puts the reduced sum $n^2 x_{\mathrm{hi}} + x_{\mathrm{lo}} < q^2$ in the range of Barrett reduction.