# All Curve25519 Parameters with Explanation

Tags: elliptic-curves

I'm trying to sum up all [Curve25519](https://cr.yp.to/ecdh/curve25519-20060209.pdf) parameter and specification reasons. Can you tell me if I missed some important reasons or parameters in the following list?:

- **Curve:** Montgomery Curve. $M_{A,B}: By^2 = x^3 + Ax^2 + x$

  **Reason:** The projective arithmetic for scalar multiplication (Montgomery ladder) is very fast.
- **Parameter** $A = 486662$.

  **Reason:** $A$ should be as small as possible but still provides an order for the elliptic curve, which is bigger than every private key ($256$ bit length). The order should be $ n \cdot p$ with $p$ being a big prime and $n \in {4,8}$ (the reasons for this is the order of Montgomery curves in general). The order of the twisted curve should have an equal form (security reasons).
- **Parameter**  $p = 2^{255} \text{- } 19$.

  **Reason:** The curve is defined over a prime field with the prime $p$. $p$ should be close to the power of $2$ to make use of a fast modulo computation. See [this post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24014/what-are-the-computational-benefits-of-primes-close-to-the-power-of-2).
- **Public keys** $ q\in \{ 0,1,2,\ldots,2^{256} - 1\}$.

  **Reason:** Every $32$ byte shall be possible, so you don't need to validate the public keys (faster). Theorem 2.1. states, that this is possible (Using extension fields).
- **Private keys** $ n\in 2^{254} + 8 \cdot \{ 0,1,2,...,2^{251} - 1\}$.

  **Reason:** Not every $32$ byte is a good key. For security reasons, the last $3$ bits should be $0$ (this prevents subgroup attacks). To prevent side-channel attacks using other scalar multiplication than Montgomery ladder, the first bit should be $1$.
- **Base point** $P = (9, y)$.

  **Reason:** To prevent small subgroup attacks, the base point has to have a big prime order. Also, for [nothing-up-my-sleeve number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing-up-my-sleeve_number) the first $x$ satisfying the curve equation that is in the large prime order is chosen.

Comment: Actually, not every public key is possible.  This can be easily show by seeing that there are only $2^{251}$ private keys, and that there is a one-to-one mapping between private keys and public keys.

Comment: So you mean that not every public key can be produced used the standard curve25519 key exchange, because there is a unique public key to every private key? But every 32 byte number can still be interpreted as a valid public key?

Comment: I doubt $0$ would be considered a 'valid public key'

Comment: If you update this question with the comments, it will be better for the community.

Comment: But I can only update the question, when i understand, what poncho means. If I get poncho right, he says, that not every q can be generated. But Bernstein states, that every q  can be interpreted as a public key, to avoid key validation.

Comment: What @poncho means is that the set of available private keys is larger than the set of private keys, which means that if you generate a list every possible public key from every possible private key, you will still have points on the curve that are not on that list. I think Bernstein means something different, which is that these points act as a valid public key, but they don't necessarily have an associated private key.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: however, there are a few values that generate tiny groups; the value $0$ is one example (which generates a group consisting of one point); there are a few others that generate small groups.  Again, I don't believe those would be considered valid public keys...

Comment: Can someone help me with the linked Code? I do not find a name for this modulo-algorithm. Does this code need to be implemented, when implementing Curve25519 or is this code used by modern CPU to handel modulo? Does this algorithm has a name?

Comment: @Titanlord Yes, it's **modular exponentiation** \([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation); [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/modular-exponentiation); [MIT](https://live-qa.ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-spring-2015/resources/mit6_042js15_session13/#:~:text=General%20Principle%20of%20Remainder%20Arithmetic)\). Commodity CPUs don't natively handle 256+ bit arithmetic, so [specialized software libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignums#Software_libraries) must be used.

Comment: There isn't just "one algorithm" for modular exponentiation; there are various methods such as "left to right method", "right to left method", Barret-reduced modexp, and Montgomery-reduced modexp (this last one being the most popular in real-world cryptography code)